# How to send a file as parameter

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to send a file as parameter to a method using php and laravel. I have my controller in which I receive, as parameter, a request. From this request, which is a file, how can i send to another method the file from my request ?

This is my code :

```
 public function analyzeKeywords(Request $request)
    {

        $file = $request->getContent();

        $transformedFile = $this->transformer(// how can i send a file here ? Typeof file of course)

    }
```

I tried to add this in order to send a file :

```
public function analyzeKeywords(Request $request)
    {

        $file = $request->file('file');
        $fileContent = $file->getContent();

        $transformedFile = $this->transformer($file);

    }
```

But I get this as an error on Postman :

> {"message":"Call to a member function getContent() on null","status_code":500}

Do you know how to resolve this ? Thank you

Comment: See [Laravel documentation about file handling](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests#files). It is `$request->file('example_file');` where `example_file` has to be replaced with whatever the file input's `name` attribute is.

Comment: This makes the $file variable equals to null.

Comment: Well have you replaced the name? Or forgot to give the file a name? Have you forgotten to set the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute in the form tag? Please update the question with more info.

Comment: `$file = $request->file('file');
        
$fileContent = $file->getContent();
        dd($fileContent);`

It returns this on postman : {"message":"Call to a member function getContent() on null","status_code":500}

Comment: Okay and the file input's name is 'file' as well? Please update the question text - others will not want to read the whole conversation.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have

`<input type="file" name="file_name" >`
in your frontend.

you should state the name of the file in the form you submitted :

```
$file = $request->file('file_name') ;
```

you can deal with the file directly, for example, if you want to get the extension of it, you can try:

```
return $file->getClientOriginalExtension() ;
```

Comment: I do have a name="file" in my front, but this doesn't change anything

Comment: what are trying to achieve exactly

Comment: I cannot explain it better than the description